# Enthought Canopy - working directory changes when code is run

Tags: python, canopy

I am trying to run a Python script in Enthought Canopy (which I use regularly). The script reads in a number of files, so I use the Canopy editor to set the working directory. However, every time the code runs, the working directory changes (without my asking it to) and the code doesn't run properly. The script itself is stored in a third directory, which is neither the working directory I want nor the directory Canopy switches to. I haven't seen this before, so would appreciate some advice.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is configurable from the drop down menu at the upper right of the Canopy python shell. See http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/quick-start/code_editor.html#change-directory